# Spark SQL insertInto() failing for partition key

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to load data from S3 transform it and then insert in a hive table with partition.

First I started with creation_date (bigint) as the partition key and it worked well, however now when I am trying to insert the same data with a creation_month partition key it is failing.

Here is the code

```
var hiveCtx = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
var df = hiveCtx.read.json("s3n://spark-feedstore/2016/1/*")
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
hiveCtx.sql("SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true")
hiveCtx.sql("SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict")

df.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
df.registerTempTable("posts")
```

The schema of the first table

```
[external_id,string,]
[tags,array<string>,]
[creation_date,bigint,]
[video_url,string,]
# Partition Information      
creation_date bigint
```

Schema of 2nd table

```
[external_id,string,]
[tags,array<string>,]
[creation_date,bigint,]
[video_url,string,]
[creation_month,date,]
# Partition Information      
creation_month bigint
```

Inserting to first table using goes fine.

```
var udf = hiveCtx .sql("select externalId as external_id, first(sourceMap['tags']) as tags, first(sourceMap['creation_date']) as creation_date, 
first(sourceMap['video_url']) as video_url
from posts group by externalId")

udf.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).partitionBy("creation_date").insertInto("posts_1")
```

However inserting to second table gives error.

```
var udf = hiveCtx .sql("select externalId as external_id, first(sourceMap['brand_hashtags']) as brand_hashtags, first(sourceMap['creation_date']) as creation_date,
```

first(sourceMap['video_url']) as video_url, trunc(from_unixtime(first(sourceMap['creation_date']) / 1000), 'MONTH') as creation_month from posts group by externalId")

```
 udf.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).partitionBy("creation_month").insertInto("posts_2")
```

Error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'cast(creation_date as array<string>)' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast LongType to ArrayType(StringType,true);
```

I am not sure what changes when we add another field creation_month. Every aspect of schema for the two tables seems exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the problem.
It was in ordering of the columns.

The field order was

```
external_id, tag, video_url, creation_date
```

But in select query I had it

```
external_id, creation_date, tag, video_url
```

Hence Hive was trying to cast creation_date as array